# Google Map Marker is showing at the left-top side

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to display a google map with draggable marker in bootstrap modal. It works perfectly but the problem is the marker is showing at the left top side of div as shown below in image.

**I wants to show in center of div**

[image]

It will shown at left top of modal. Here is my code for showing google map.

```
function init() {
      var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');

      $('.mapModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
          google.maps.event.trigger(mapCanvas, "resize");
      });

        //var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(23.0203135, 72.5561606);
        var myLatlng = {lat: 23.019523540982888, lng: 72.55628934603271};
        /*
          23.019523540982888
          72.55628934603271
          23.0203135
          72.5561606
        */
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 15,
            center: myLatlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            draggable: true,
            map: map,
            position: myLatlng,
            title: "Your location"
        });
        //To Fill Lat Long
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function (event) {
            document.getElementById("lat").value = event.latLng.lat();
            document.getElementById("lng").value = event.latLng.lng();
        });
}
```

Comment: `shown at Right-bottom of modal` - actually, the marker seems to be top left `{lat: 23.019523540982888, lng: 72.55628934603271}` is exactly where that marker is shown

Comment: how to solve this ?

Comment: how to solve what? the marker is in the correct place

Comment: but display is in top left as shown in figure

Comment: oh, sorry, thought you said "marker is showing inaccurate result" ... but the marker is in the correct position on the map

Comment: yes you are right @JaromandaX. but it is not in center. so how can i set marker to center of div. in my modal it is shown at right corner of div as i post image. i want in center

Comment: must be some code you're not showing ... [here's your code in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t1qqzd78/) looks perfect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `map.setCenter(myLatlng);` and it will works.

```
var map;
    //google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", init());
    function init() {
      var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
      var myLatlng = {lat: 23.019523540982888, lng: 72.55628934603271};

      $('.mapModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
          google.maps.event.trigger(mapCanvas, "resize");
          map.setCenter(myLatlng);
      });

        //var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(23.019523540982888, 72.55628934603271);
        /*
          23.019523540982888
          72.55628934603271
          23.0203135
          72.5561606
        */
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 15,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(23.0203135, 72.5561606),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, myOptions);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            draggable: true,
            map: map,
            position: myLatlng,
            title: "Your location"
        });
        //To Fill Lat Long
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function (event) {
            document.getElementById("lat").value = event.latLng.lat();
            document.getElementById("lng").value = event.latLng.lng();
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd suggest that you put your Google Maps logic and all code that creates the map inside bootstrap modal event; after it has been created, like this:

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
  // .. put you map code here or just hook your custom function
});
```

then see if your map is centered. Also make sure that you give your div or element explicit height for ex: `<div id="map_canvas" style="height: 500px;"></div>`